# How would I add a counter in this scenario?

Tags: c++, counter

new to programming. I made this simple program that reads a bank pin but I am getting an infinite loop. I know that I am supposed to add a counter as that is what my teacher said but I don't know how to actually implement it. If anyone could help that would be amazing.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main() {
  int pin = 12345;
  int input;
  

  cout << "Please enter your pin." << endl;
  cin >> input;
  while (input != 12345) {
    cout << "INCORRECT PIN. TRY AGAIN." << endl;
    cout << "Please enter your pin." << endl;

    

  }
  else if (input==12345) {
    cout << "ACCESS GRANTED. WELCOME TO YOUR BANK" << endl;
  }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first step is defining the specification to implement. For example, counter to count what?

Comment: Is counter mean how many times incorrect pin?

Comment: What is this? A while... else loop? I've heard about it as some bizarre Python-thing, but I had no idea it also exists in C++ :-)

Comment: You read `input` only once, even if first read is incorrect

Comment: If you want to count the incorrect pin entries than just take a variable named as incorrectPinCount outside loop and when it reaches maximum number of efforts than break the loop.

Comment: You will not get an infinite loop from this code because `else` without preceding `if` is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You are not taking input again in while loop. That's why its running infinite loop.
Try this

```
int main() {
  int pin = 12345;
  int input;
  

  cout << "Please enter your pin." << endl;
  cin >> input;
  while (input != pin) {
    cout << "INCORRECT PIN. TRY AGAIN." << endl;
    cout << "Please enter your pin." << endl;
    cin >> input;
  }
  if (input==pin) {
    cout << "ACCESS GRANTED. WELCOME TO YOUR BANK" << endl;
  }

 return 0;
}
```

and if you want some counter like if user enter wrong pin more than 3 times you should not let him access bank accout.

```
int main() {
  int pin = 12345;
  int input;
  const int times = 3;
  int counter = 0;

  do{
    cout << "Please enter your pin." << endl;
    cin >> input;
    if(input != pin){
       cout << "INCORRECT PIN. TRY AGAIN." << endl;
       counter++;
    } else {
       break;
    }
    if(counter == times){
        cout << "You cannot access your account. You enter wrong pin for 3 times\n";
        return 0;
    }
  }while(input != pin);
  if (input==pin) {
    cout << "ACCESS GRANTED. WELCOME TO YOUR BANK" << endl;
  }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd make it`if(not (cin >> input)) break;` just to make it exit if the user closes `stdin` but +1.

Comment: We need to give him at least some tries to input correct pin..

Comment: Yes, and `if(not (cin >> input)) break;` does just that. It only breaks if no integer was entered at all. You may want to consider `std::getline(std::cin, <some std::string variable>)` instead and then convert it to an `int`.